# can't create directory with ebextension commands

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy via Jenkins a Laravel application and I'm getting this error:

```
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover

In PackageManifest.php line 165:
  The /var/app/ondeck/bootstrap/cache directory must be present and writable.
```

So I'm trying to create this directory via ebextension command file, just like this:

```
commands:

    01directories:
        command: "mkdir -p bootstrap/cache"
        cwd: "/var/app/ondeck"

    02directories:
        command: "chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache"
        cwd: "/var/app/ondeck"

    03directories:
        command: "chmod -R 777 storage"
        cwd: "/var/app/ondeck"
```

But the error persists. It looks the mkdir command is not working.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: partially solved by creating dummy files on .gitignore folders =(

Comment: Before the first command is performed, does `bootstrap` exist?

Answer (score 2):

You should simply try to use `sudo mkdir -p /bootstrap/cache`. Using `sudo` worked for me. If the `bootstrap` directory already exists of course. As mentioned by @profgan.

Comment: Yes, if I were to remote into the ELB instance each time, but that is not realistic. There is a way to do with with config files.